# Swing and JOGL 2

Tags: java, opengl, render, jogl

How do I render OpenGL (JOGL and not immediate mode) in a Swing Component? I've tried the example off of the OpenGL website but it doesn't seem to be built to work with swing. The only ones that are made for swing seem to be deprecated and immediate mode.

```
HelloTriangle helloTriangle = new HelloTriangle();
GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4);
GLCapabilities glCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glProfile);
GLJPanel glPanel = new GLJPanel(glCapabilities);
final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas( glCapabilities );
glcanvas.addGLEventListener( helloTriangle );


glcanvas.setSize( 700, 300 );
glcanvas.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 300);
glPanel.add(glcanvas);
mainScreen.add(glPanel, null);
```

This is what I"m trying to get to work right now.

Comment: Afaik you can't, this is because swing components don't have a native peer (or whnd) of their own but share the windows peer that they are attached to

Comment: You can use a Java.awt.Canvas

Comment: How would I go about using Java.awt.Canvas? I used it for immediate mode before and it worked but now I can't get it to work for gl4???

Comment: You'll need to provide a runnable example of what you've tried, maybe jolg has its own surface?

Comment: That's how I used it in immediate mode anyway.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing#JOGL_in_Swing)

Comment: Probably more work than you want, but you could render the OpenGL view to a FrameBuffer object, extract the resulting texture data, turn that into a BufferedImage then display that image on your swing component, basically the similar technique to making a screenshot in OpenGL.

Comment: JOGL 4 doesn't exist, please don't keep a confusing title. JOGL version != OpenGL version: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html @Jere GLJPanel already uses a FBO, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. I advise you to look at elect's suggestion.

Comment: @TedGress Your code is plain wrong. Don't put a GLCanvas inside a GLJPanel. You just have to replace GLWindow by GLCanvas or GLJPanel and put it into a JFrame like in the example he quotes above.

Comment: JOGL 4 does exist. Check your references.

Comment: OK. So I have a class extending GLEventListener and I have code stubs to implement it. In each code stub I have a print statement. Everything else in the class (print statements) work.  The print statements in the code stub don't print anything out though

Comment: public class UserInterface  extends JFrame implements GLEventListener{